# B vs P pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm a native Arabic speaker -Egyptian- we don't have the V & P sounds natively, I'm fully capable of pronouncing the V sound & telling the difference between it & the F sound perfectly, but I struggle with P, I don't know if I'm pronouncing it as B or not & I struggle with telling the difference between the two even though I know it, both are a bobbing sound caused by the release of air build up, with the difference being that the B one is voiced, this is the exact difference between F & V with the V being voiced, but they both feel so short and exactly the same, for example Pat vs Bat, isn't the a kind of voiced, all I hear is the bob sound followed by a voiced a then the T sound, I feel that the bob is stronger in P, is this the only difference or am I missing something?

Is there any words in which the difference is more prominent, & is there a way to pronounce P correctly even if I can't tell the difference?

by the way I can in most cases guess correctly if a word -even if it's the first time hearing it- is written with P or B but I can't pinpoint the difference in hearing

Comment: This is often the hard part in listening and speaking a new language: sounds that do not exist in your own language.  I have no trouble hearing *P* and *B*.  But I am sure there are things in Arabic that would be hard for me to hear.

Comment: In American English, /p/ is usually undistinguishable from /b/ except when it begins a stressed syllable, when it is aspirated. _Pin_ is [pʰɪn], very different from _bin_ [bɪn]; but with _spin, stop, staple_, for instance, you can use either [p] or [b]. If the P is spelled double, then you need to devoice: _happy_ doesn't sound right with a [b]. If you hold it longer, you have more time to devoice it. Don't aspirate it unless it starts a stressed syllable, like _press_.

Comment: Think of the "pop" sound -- a sudden release of air.  This (obviously) goes with "p" -- the "b" sound is more restrained.  But associated with this are some very subtle motions of the lips and tongue which differ between the two sounds.

Comment: @JohnLawler Do you have a *staple–stable* merger then? :)

Comment: I can distinguish them if I need to, but normally I don't. Any more than I need to distinguish _bear, bare,_ and _bear_.

Comment: Arabic doesn't have a native P so the only thing you can do is *practice*. According to Wikipedia, P only occurs in foreign words such as 'Pakistan' but it's pronounced with a B.

Comment: I have been experimenting a little and, as a British English speaker, I find that I purse my lips slightly more for "p" than for "b", which fits the meaning of some of the words starting with "p" such a "picky" and "prissy". I also find that I have a slight tendency to turn up the corners of my mouth when pronouncing "p" sounds and to turn them down when pronouncing "b" sounds. This results in the sound being formed more against the upper teeth for the "p" sounds. Try it, if it doesn't work for you forget this comment.

Comment: Try this: pat, the air comes out, you blow it out. Hold a piece of paper in front of your mouth. If it moves, you're good. NOW, bat: do the same thing without blowing out any air. The paper should not move at all. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try “P” by just exhaling heavy while slightly puckering your lips, similar to simply blowing candles out. Only use your breath and lips, not your vocal cord.

Try “B” by puckering your lips firmly and as you exhale vocalize the sound a lamb makes “bah, bah”

I’ve never tried to help someone with a pronunciation that isn’t in front of me, in person… So I’m hoping my advice helps but if not then don’t worry, it’s likely due to my inexperience with teaching pronunciation, especially via Internet. If you are still having difficulties, let me know if you’d like to try via phone call or video call. I wouldn’t mind taking the time to try a different method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How can they "vocalize the sound a lamb makes" if they can't hear it??

Comment: Since we want answers on this site to help all readers, not just the OP, "let me know if you’d like to try via phone call or video call" is unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you whisper the word *bee* over and over again, you will begin to notice it sounds like *pea*. That is because you are emitting breath without using your voice.  So what you have to do is purse your lips as if you were going to make 'b', but instead say 'he'.

Comment: The reason this works is that both whispering and saying "he" will cause you to aspirate the sound.

Answer (score 0):

I can feel for you and your difficulties. It is the ventriloquist with his alphabet of frozen lipped vocabulary that substitutes 'D' and 'T' for both 'P' and 'B'. It is only the context and words used that trick the ear into hearing the expected consonant. The only cure will be to expose yourself to the brunt of the language you wish to adapt to. For this I can recommend Python, Monty at length; http://montypython.50webs.com/scripts/Series_3/45.htm   This routine is about an Englishman who adapts to his own difficulties.

Comment: That transcription is bit off from the recording I have...

Comment: @Jim  It is also off from the book I have of all their scripts. Many versions are about.  Tis pity we have only TV from the 70s to parse and argue. Much better remains of Shakespeare and his environs.

Answer (score 0):

The two sounds involve the same mechanical acts of the mouth. The "B" sound is infinitesimally slower which trends toward a kind of Buzzing sound, like the Bee insect's wings. The "P" sound is faster and sharper. Compare to a bang from fireworks. An explosive PoP.

As a side note, the "Z" sound uses different mouth actions but the same vocal cord action of "B", as in buZZing. It's a vibration, not a popping sound.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little whiz of air in the P sound and none in the B sound.
It's kind of like actually saying a little H sound (as in "hooray") right after the P.

When both Americans and the English pronounce P, they blow a little air into the vowel. (Yes, they blow into P, no pun intended :)

It can be heard very well in the [**B**eekeeping sketch with Mr. **P**rawnbaum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGFz9gt0-Fc&t=26s).

Answer (score 0):

[Geoff Lindsey's video on aspiration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PSdlctYBsw) covers this well. In English, the distinction between /p/ and /b/ is often one of aspiration rather than one of voicing *per se.* When /p/ occurs at the start of a word or at the start of a stressed syllable, it is generally aspirated, whereas /b/ is never aspirated. As John Lawler commented:

> In American English, /p/ is usually undistinguishable from /b/ except when it begins a stressed syllable, when it is aspirated. *Pin* is [pʰɪn], very different from *bin* [bɪn]; but with *spin, stop, staple,* for instance, you can use either [p] or [b]. If the P is spelled double, then you need to devoice: *happy* doesn't sound right with a [b]. If you hold it longer, you have more time to devoice it. Don't aspirate it unless it starts a stressed syllable, like *press.*

/p/ also tends to shorten the length of the preceding vowel sound due to prefortis clipping. Moreover, if the preceding sound is /aɪ/, then /p/ can trigger ["American raising"](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/truly.html) in American English, causing a change in the starting point of that diphthong.

As Geoff Lindsey states, in some cases there *is* no difference: the "p" sound in "speech" should arguably be transcribed as [b]. As John Lawler notes above, there are other words in which the voicing is more relevant, e.g. the double *p* in words like "happy."

Comment: You *always* need to pronounce *p* without voicing!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Not in words like "speech," [as Geoff Lindsey states.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=U37hX8NPgjQ) John Lawler says above that "with spin, stop, staple, for instance, you can use either [p] or [b]."

Comment: Yes, there's no aspiration in syllable onsets following an initial fricative, true, so the primary distinction is lost in that environment. But it's not a good way to present it that there are a few places where the lack of voicing is important, when the fact is that it's important in the vast, vast, vast majority of cases.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Feel free to post your own answer if you have more information. I'm following Lawler in saying that "In American English, /p/ is usually undistinguishable from /b/ except when it begins a stressed syllable, when it is aspirated."

Comment: Is your point that, when aspirated, /p/ is also not voiced? Or is it that /b/ gets devoiced more often than /p/ gets voiced?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I have edited my answer to be somewhat more clear; if you would like to post an answer that you believe is more correct or complete, I will gladly delete mine and upvote yours instead.

Comment: (1) You can no more use a [b] in *canopy* than you can in *happy* and (2) double orthographic < p >s meaning nothing whatsoever, nothing, in terms of the pronunciation of the /p/. (3) Your very own post says that a syllable-final [p] will result in pre-fortis clipping, so it's a no brainer that if you use a [b] you will get the wrong contrast. (4) The use of /b/ instead of /p/ by Arabic speakers is a well-known problem and is not by any means restricted to [p] in word or foot initial contexts. (5) You might get away with a [p] when a [b] is required, but it  doesn't work the other way round.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I don't think it's worth arguing this point in the comments. If you have your own answer to the OP's question--and it seems that you do--please post one.